# Edit a file without changing it existing name

Tags: c#

I'm trying to edit a txt file without changing its name but I'm stump on what to do next.

Here what I have:

```
    private void btnApply_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(richTbWrite.Text);

        sw.WriteLine(richTbWrite.Text);
        sw.Close();
        this.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Why are you stumped? What has stumped you? Why are you using `richTbWrite.Text` for both the filename and the file contents?

Comment: So what? What Do you want to edit?, where is the content of text file?

Comment: I guess it finding a way to keep the name for the file. Will I need to copy whats already there. @John

Comment: @blue If you're opening the file somewhere you should reuse the filename. And yes, unless you're _appending_ to the file, you will need to copy the original contents into your editor, and then save the amended version.

Comment: The content of the txt file is in c:\documents @PrathapG. The reason _**richTBWrite.Text**_ is there is because I was trying to figure out a way to solve my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private void btnApply_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (StreamWriter stream = new StreamWriter(richTbWrite.Text, true))
        {
            stream.WriteLine("some text here");
        }
    }
```

Comment: @blue11233 You can add text in the existing file without changing the file-name by using above code

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 1):

I think richTbWrite is RichText box. First I will open file and read content and assign to rich text box. Then saving to file content of rich text box to same file again.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     string fileName = @"C:\Users\Public\TestFolder\WriteText.txt";
     string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(fileName);
     richTbWrite.Text = text;
}

private void btnApply_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     string fileName = @"C:\Users\Public\TestFolder\WriteText.txt";
     string content = richTbWrite.Text;
     System.IO.File.WriteAllText(fileName, content);
}
```